# ReactJS not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a fully functional site. It works in every browser, except IE.
Here is my

```
<script src="build/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/md5.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>

<script type="text/jsx" src="components/newsfeed.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="components/services.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="components/footer.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="components/app.js"></script>
```

On Chrome/Firefox I get the site running, on IE11 I can see, that the app.js was downloaded twice. And apparently not started.

There was nothing in IE11 console, but later found out, that I was missing some security update from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44431 .
After installing that I can see IE complaining about Newsfeed not defined.
It is caused by

```
React.render(
    <NewsFeed tagFilter={tagFilter}/>,
    document.getElementById('newsFeed')
);
```

being translated into (visible in IE console)

```
React.render(
    React.createElement(NewsFeed, {tagFilter: tagFilter}),
    document.getElementById('newsFeed')
);
```

And the browser than complains about missing **;**

Any clues what might be wrong? It works in web browsers. Only IE does this.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console ?

Comment: no, it is totally clear. That is what surprises me the most. It says, that the first case was initiated during HTML preparsing. The second one XMLHTTP requests. It seems like if React didn't start the app.

Comment: Are you using a meta tag to make sure IE is using the latest version of its engine? Does it magically start working if you have the developer console open during page load?

Comment: I'm using <html>, so it should be treated as HTML5 (at least I hope). Yes, I've got the console open.

Comment: Adding doctype and meta enabling edge rendering in IE also didn't help.

Comment: Now I can at least see something in IE11 console - it didn't work, installing some security update (for x64, x86 is available also) from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44431